# ULN2803A Input Pull-Downs

Tags: relay

Recently I need use [ULN2803A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2803a.pdf) to drive relays. I've never used it before. I have some questions about it.

1. I don't find the leakage information (Icbo) of it. So if the input of it is floating, what's the output state?  On or Off? If I can left the input safely floating?
2. In the datasheet section 9.3:

> The GPIO voltage is converted to base current via the 2.7kΩ resistor connected between the input and base of the pre-driver Darlington NPN. The 7.2kΩ & 3.0kΩ resistors connected between the base and emitter of each respective NPN act as pull-downs and suppress the amount of leakage that may occur from the input.

I don't understand the words "suppress the amount of leakage that may occur from the input". What's it mean? Where the leakage from and to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The emitter can never be open with respect to the base as there are internal resistors etc., so Icbo is inappropriate. Leakage can occur from the collector to base of the input transistor. That is shunted away by the series resistors so it doesn't turn the output transistor on and no significant voltage appears at the input.

[image]

Icex is the parameter (50uA maximum). Figure 4. Icex test circuit illustrates the circuit with input open.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. For a normal transistor, which parameter can give some information about the leakage current from collector to base?

Comment: Icbo is leakage collector to base with emitter open. Hence the name.

Comment: The edited version is more clear now.

Comment: @diverger Yes, I agree. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

1. As shown in section 9.2, both bases are pulled to ground. As such, the floating state is off.
2. The leakage would be from a high input to ground through all three resistors. Lower resistances would result in higher leakage.

Comment: That is, the "leakage" actually means a part of the input current, right?

Comment: It does say "from the input" in the paragraph.